# Proxy objects to simulate a soon-to-be-created database

Tags: c#, oop, data-binding

I have a database that contains "widgets", let's say. Widgets have properties like Length and Width, for example. The original lower-level API for creating wdigets is a mess, so I'm writing a higher-level set of functions to make things easier for callers. The database is strange, and I don't have good control over the timing of the creation of a widget object. Specifically, it can't be created until the later stages of processing, after certain other things have happened first. But I'd like my callers to *think* that a widget object has been created at an earlier stage, so that they can get/set its properties from the outset.

So, I implemented a "ProxyWidget" object that my callers can play with. It has private fields like private_Length and private_Width that can store the desired values. Then, it also has public properties Length and Width, that my callers can access. If the caller tells me to set the value of the Width property, the logic is:

- If the corresponding widget object already exists in the database, then set
  its Width property
- If not, store the given width value in the private_Width field for later use.

At some later stage, when I'm sure that the widget object has been created in the database, I copy all the values: copy from private_Width to the database Width field, and so on (one field/property at a time, unfortunately).

This works OK for one type of widget. But I have about 50 types, each with about 20 different fields/properties, and this leads to an unmaintainable mess. I'm wondering if there is a smarter approach.  Perhaps I could use reflection to create the "proxy" objects and copy field/property data in a generic way, rather than writing reams of repetitive code? Factor out common code somehow? Can I learn anything from "data binding" patterns? I'm a mathematician, not a programmer, and I have an uneasy feeling that my current approach is just plain dumb. My code is in C#.

Comment: Are you notified in any way at the moment when the widget is created in the database? Otherwise, how do you know when you can save your buffered changes?

Comment: Not really "notified", but there is a function I can call to find out whether the widget exists in the db yet, and there is a point in time when I'm sure it exists, without even asking. At this latter point in time, I save the buffered data.

Answer (score 1):

First, in my experience, manually coding a data access layer *can* feel like a lot of repetitive work (putting an ORM in place, such as NHibernate or Entity Framework, *might* somewhat alleviate this issue), and updating a legacy data access layer *is* awful work, especially when it consists of many parts.

Some things are unclear in your question, but I suppose it is still possible to give a high-level answer. These are meant to give you some ideas:

- You can build `ProxyWidget` either as an alternative implementation for `Widget` (or whatever the widget class from the existing low-level API is called), or you can implement it "on top of", or as a "wrapper around", `Widget`. This is the [Adapter design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern).

  ```
  public sealed class ExistingTerribleWidget { … }

  public sealed class ShinyWidget // this is the wrapper that sits on top of the above
  {
      public ShinyWidget(ExistingTerribleWidget underlying) { … }
      private ExistingTerribleWidget underlying;
      … // perform all real work by delegating to `underlying` as appropriate  
  }
  ```

  I would recommend that (at least while there is still code using the existing low-level API) you use this pattern instead of creating a completely separate `Widget` implementation, because if ever there is a database schema change, you will have to update two different APIs. If you build your new `EasyWidget` class as a wrapper on top of the existing API, it could remain unchanged and only the underlying implementation would have to be updated.
- You describe `ProxyWidget` having two functions (1) Allow modifications to an already persisted widget; and (2) Buffer for a new widget, which will be added to the database later.

  You could *perhaps* simplify your design if you have one common base type and two sub-classes: One for new widgets that haven't been persisted yet, and one for already persisted widgets. The latter subtype possibly has an additional database `ID` property so that the existing widget can be identified, loaded, modified, and updated in the database:

  ```
  interface IWidget { /* define all the properties required for a widget */ }

  interface IWidgetTemplate : IWidget
  {
      IPersistedWidget Create();
      bool TryLoadFrom(IWidgetRepository repository, out IPersistedWidget matching);
  }

  interface IPersistedWidget : IWidget
  {
      Guid Id { get; }
      void SaveChanges();
  }
  ```

  This is one example for the [Builder design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).
- If you need to write similar code for many classes (for example, your 50+ database object types) you could consider using [T4 text templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb126445.aspx). This just makes writing code less repetitive; but you will still have to define your 50+ objects somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your ideas. My upper-level NewWidget is indeed a wrapper around an OldWidget, much as you described. I can't change the code that implements OldWidget, so I can't get OldWidget and NewWidget to inherit from the same interface, can I ? It would be nice/natural if they could -- their properties are almost exactly the same. The T4 text templates are interesting. I used a similar idea to write the original code, except that I used Excel and macros. So, I didn't write the code by hand, but I'm still uneasy about it -- 15000 lines of repetitive babble, and it often needs to be updated.

Comment: **1.** T4 is nice because it integrates fairly well with Visual Studio & the build system. But I'm not a salesman -- it's just a possibility, don't blindly follow my suggestion. **2.** No, you cannot add an interface to an existing type. You can only create a new wrapper type and implement the interface there.